# Shlex does not pass multiple consecutive commands properly to subprocess when separated by semicolon

Tags: python, python-3.x, subprocess, shlex

I have two folders. I have created temp files as below

```sh
$ touch -t 1604031305 files/tmpfile files2/tmpfile && tree .
.
├── files
│   └── tmpfile
├── files2
│   └── tmpfile
└── test.py

2 directories, 3 files
```

Now I can execute the following `find` command and `rm` the desired files.

```sh
$ find /path/to/files/ -type f -mtime +3 -exec rm -f {} \; ; find /path/to/files2 -type f -mtime +6 -exec rm -f {} \; ; tree .
.
├── files
├── files2
└── test.py

2 directories, 1 file
```

My requirement is that I should be able to do the above `find` commands, by using `Subprocess.Popen`. But it throws an error.

`test.py`

```py
import shlex
import subprocess

cmd1 = "find /path/to/files/ -type f -mtime +3 -exec rm -f {} \;"
cmd2 = "find /path/to/files2/ -type f -mtime +6 -exec rm -f {} \; "

cmdsplit1 = shlex.split(cmd1)
cmdsplit2 = shlex.split(cmd2)
cmdsplit = cmdsplit1 + cmdsplit2

print(cmdsplit1)
print(cmdsplit2)
print(cmdsplit1 + cmdsplit2)

subprocess.Popen(cmdsplit1) # works on its own
subprocess.Popen(cmdsplit2) # works on its own
subprocess.Popen(cmdsplit) # combination of the two does not work
```

And the output I get is the following

```sh
$ python3 test.py
# cmdsplit 1 works individually
['find', '/path/to/files/', '-type', 'f', '-mtime', '+3', '-exec', 'rm', '-f', '{}', ';']
# cmdsplit 2 works individually
['find', '/path/to/files2/', '-type', 'f', '-mtime', '+6', '-exec', 'rm', '-f', '{}', ';']
# cmdsplit throws an error
['find', '/path/to/files/', '-type', 'f', '-mtime', '+3', '-exec', 'rm', '-f', '{}', ';', 'find', '/path/to/files2/', '-type', 'f', '-mtime', '+6', '-exec', 'rm', '-f', '{}', ';']
find: paths must precede expression: `find'
```

I noticed that a `;` is missing from the original command. So when I change the `cmds` to the following,

```py
cmd1 = "find /path/to/files/ -type f -mtime +3 -exec rm -f {} \; ; " # added the extra ; here
cmd2 = "find /path/to/files2/ -type f -mtime +6 -exec rm -f {} \; "
```

I get the following output

```sh
$ python3 test.py 
['find', '/path/to/files/', '-type', 'f', '-mtime', '+3', '-exec', 'rm', '-f', '{}', ';', ';']
['find', '/path/to/files2/', '-type', 'f', '-mtime', '+6', '-exec', 'rm', '-f', '{}', ';']
['find', '/path/to/files/', '-type', 'f', '-mtime', '+3', '-exec', 'rm', '-f', '{}', ';', ';', 'find', '/path/to/files2/', '-type', 'f', '-mtime', '+6', '-exec', 'rm', '-f', '{}', ';']
find: paths must precede expression: `;'
find: paths must precede expression: `;'
```

I am not sure where I'm going wrong.

NOTE: I don't have the option of passing the strings directly to the subprocess. The codebase is in such a way that I can't modify that part. I **have** to pass it as a string, which **will** be parsed by `shlex.split()` and passed on to Subprocess. I also don't have the option of passing the multiple `find` commands one by one, meaning I can't call the API multiple times, I should pass it in one go.

Comment: A subprocess with the default option of `shell=False` *cannot* run multiple commands separated by semicolons - the first element of the list is the one command that will be run, everything else is parameters to that command.  If you can't change that, you're left with the ugly option of running `sh -c`, with your entire semicolon-separated command string as the second parameter (in other words, emulating what `shell=True` would do).  Good luck getting the quoting right on that...

Comment: @jasonharper Will running with `sh -c` having any bad side effects? Is it bad practice? If so why?

Comment: Well, the default is `shell=False` for a reason - if the command is run via a shell, then anyone who can control any part of the command string can run arbitrary code on your machine.  But it looks like your commands are entirely static, so there wouldn't be such a security issue here.

Comment: @jasonharper thanks. It'd be helpful if you could put up an answer and working solution if possible and I can accept it as the answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks to jasonharper.

Apparently only this works for my use case.

```py
import shlex
import subprocess

cmd1 = "find /home/kishore/testshlex/files/ -type f -mtime +3 -exec rm -f {} \; ; "
cmd2 = "find /home/kishore/testshlex/files2/ -type f -mtime +6 -exec rm -f {} \; "

cmds = cmd1 + cmd2

sh = "/bin/sh -c"
cmd = shlex.split(sh)
cmd.append(cmds)

subprocess.Popen(cmd)
```