# command for subprocess popen not working with shell=False

Tags: python, shell, subprocess, popen, shlex

I am trying to run a subprocess with my own iptables rule for a subprocess using subprocess.open. The command works with `shell=True`. But when I remove the shell option, which it sets the shell option to false. The command doesn't work anymore.

Here is the working code:

```
HOST = localhost
PORT: 8000
group_name = "no-external-internet"
subprocess.Popen(
            f"addgroup --system {group_name}; "
            f"iptables -A OUTPUT -m owner --gid-owner {group_name} -d {HOST} -p tcp --sport {PORT} -j ACCEPT; "
            f"iptables  -A OUTPUT -m owner --gid-owner {group_name} -j REJECT; "
            f"ip6tables -A OUTPUT -m owner --gid-owner {group_name} -j REJECT; "
            f"sg {group_name} './run.sh {HOST}:{PORT}'",
            shell=True,
            cwd="some directory",
            preexec_fn=os.setsid,
        )
```

When I remove the `shell=True` and used the shlex to split my command:

```
subprocess.Popen(
            shlex.split(
                f"addgroup --system {group_name}; "
                f"iptables -A OUTPUT -m owner --gid-owner {group_name} -d {HOST} -p tcp --sport {PORT} -j ACCEPT; "
                f"iptables  -A OUTPUT -m owner --gid-owner {group_name} -j REJECT; "
                f"ip6tables -A OUTPUT -m owner --gid-owner {group_name} -j REJECT; "
                f"sg {group_name} './run.sh {HOST}:{PORT}'",
            ),
            cwd="some directory",
            preexec_fn=os.setsid,
        )
```

I got errors:

```
Unknown option: m

Unknown option: gid-owner

Option d is ambiguous (debug, disabled-login, disabled-password)

Unknown option: p

Unknown option: sport

Unknown option: j

Unknown option: m

Unknown option: gid-owner

Unknown option: j

Unknown option: m

Unknown option: gid-owner

Unknown option: j
```

I print the split result and it looks okay:

> ['addgroup', '--system', 'no-external-internet;', 'iptables', '-A', 'OUTPUT', '-m', 'owner', '--gid-owner', 'no-external-internet', '-d', '127.0.0.1', '-p', 'tcp', '--sport', '8000', '-j', 'ACCEPT;', 'iptables', '-A', 'OUTPUT', '-m', 'owner', '--gid-owner', 'no-external-internet', '-j', 'REJECT;', 'ip6tables', '-A', 'OUTPUT', '-m', 'owner', '--gid-owner', 'no-external-internet', '-j', 'REJECT;', 'sg', 'no-external-internet', './run.sh 127.0.0.1:8000']

Why this doesn't work and how could I solve it

Comment: Running a sequence of commands separated by semicolons is a feature that the shell provides.  You can only run a single command at a time otherwise.

Comment: @jasonharper So for commands with semicolon, I could only run it with shell=True? Is there any work around. Shell=True seems to be more vulnerable

Comment: `shell=True` is only vulnerable if an external party has control over any part of the command string; the issue is that if *you* are able to separate commands with a semicolon, *they* could insert a semicolon in whatever substring they're providing, followed by any command they want to execute.  The alternative is to run the commands with separate `subprocess` calls - since they don't seem to share environment variables or CWD changes, there shouldn't be any problem in running them separately.

Comment: Thanks @jasonharper
https://stackoverflow.com/a/62312769/12248597
Found the working solution! Believe you were there too :D